# var Double type swift crashing

Tags: swift, double, var

I am making a Calculator app and it crashes when I get to a high number.
Here is the code.

```
var accumulator: Double = 0.0
 func updateDisplay() {
    // If the value is an integer, don't show a decimal point
     let iAcc = Int(accumulator)


    if accumulator - Double(iAcc) == 0 {
      numField.text = "\(iAcc)"

    } else {

        numField.text = "\(accumulator)"
    }
}
```

and here is the error

```
fatal error: floating point value can not be converted to Int because it is greater than Int.max
```

If any one could help that would be great!

Comment: What is `accumulator`, could you print `accumulator` at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use this extension to prevent your crash:

```
extension Double {
    // If you don't want your code crash on each overflow, use this function that operates on optionals
    // E.g.: Int(Double(Int.max) + 1) will crash:
    // fatal error: floating point value can not be converted to Int because it is greater than Int.max
    func toInt() -> Int? {
        if self > Double(Int.min) && self < Double(Int.max) {
            return Int(self)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

So ,  your code will be:

```
...
let iAcc = accumulator.toInt()
...
```